# Is it "okay" for my view decorator to add an item to kwargs that are passed to the view function?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-decorators

I wrote a decorator to wrap a lot of my views with. It essentially checks to see that the request.user is the 'owner' of an object.

```
# urls.py
...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.my_view, name='my_view'),
]


# decorators.py
...
def user_can_access_object(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=kwargs['pk'])

        if request.user == my_object.owner:
            # I actually do more to ensure the user can access, but this is for my SO question to keep it simple.
            kwargs['my_object'] = my_object  # <-- Am I doing something terrible here?
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

        else:
            raise PermissionDenied

    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap


# views.py
...
@login_required
@user_can_access_object
def my_view(request, pk, my_object):  # Now that 'my_object' is set, my_view must be setup to accept it. Also, 'pk' is the pk for my_object.
    """"
    A view that does something to 'my_object'.

    """
    ...
    some_function(my_object)
    ...
    return render(request, "my_template.html", some_context)
```

Here is my original solution.

```
# decorators.py
...
def user_can_access_object(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=kwargs['pk'])

        if request.user == my_object.owner:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

        else:
            raise PermissionDenied

    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap


# views.py
...
@login_required
@user_can_access_object
def my_view(request, pk):  # This seems to be better, or at least more clear, It seems like the decorator is playing nicely and not modifying the request kwargs.
    """"
    A view that does something to 'my_object'.

    """
    my_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)  # My concern is that 'my_object' is looked up twice. And that seems gross and isn't this an extra database query?
    ...
    some_function(my_object)

    return render(request, "my_template.html", some_context)
```

My greatest fear is that when `my_object` is added to kwargs, it basically makes the view *rely* on the decorator. That just seems like bad practice but maybe it's not.

Comment: Note that due to its scope `my_object ` is available inside your view anyway. You probably want to use class based views here with custom `dispatch()` method.

Comment: Following the comment above, instead of changing `kwargs`, you could do something like: `try: my_object except NameError: my_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)`. Then the view no more rely on the decorator.

Comment: Sometimes in this use case, it could be more interesting to test the user permission before, and then not display at all the link the user is not allowed to follow.